# Fix scroll on content while menu is expanded

Tags: html, css, menu

Im trying to make a mobile menu scrollable while keeping page content at a fixed point when both are open. You will notice the undesired visibility of the scrolling of the menu through the bottom of the page

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x64c1L83/3/)

```
    <div class="navigation mobile">
        <div class="menu-wrap">

            <div class="project-tile">
                <div class="copy">
                    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
                    <a href="#">View project</a>
                </div><!-- /copy -->
            </div><!-- /project-tile -->

            <div class="project-tile">
                <div class="copy">
                    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
                    <a href="#">View project</a>
                </div><!-- /copy -->
            </div><!-- /project-tile -->

        </div><!-- /menu-wrap -->
    </div><!-- /navigation -->

    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger mobile" />
    <label class="mobile" for="nav-trigger">Menu</label>


<div id="content" class="site-wrap">
Copy</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the positioning of the navigation element and adding an overflow-scroll, like so

```
.navigation
{
   position: fixed;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x64c1L83/3/

Comment: Perfect!! That's exactly what I was after, thanks :)